# MySQL select grouping multiple rows from same table

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-select

I'm trying to create a query to select multiple rows from the same table grouping them like an array. 
Now i'm selecting them using php like this:

```
$tks = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hof ORDER BY tks DESC LIMIT 5");

$top_ths = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hof ORDER BY ths DESC LIMIT 1");

$top_tha = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hof ORDER BY tha DESC LIMIT 1");

----
```

I would like to merge them in a single query so i get an associative array.
Something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM hol ORDER BY tks DESC LIMIT 5) AS tks
UNION
(SELECT * FROM hol ORDER BY ths DESC LIMIT 1) AS top_ths
```

So tks contains all the 5 rows and top_ths contains 1 row.
Is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Why not? Have you tried that query already?

Comment: Yup... You have done it the right way. That's the answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. But it tells me there's an error near 'AS tks... :(

Comment: You do not have to alias the queries within a union.

Comment: What do you mean Shadow ?

Comment: @Mr.M remove `as alias` everywhere in your query

Comment: @splash58, but then how can i distinguish a group from the other ? I'll get only the total rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to undersatnd from wich group row is, make additional field

```
(SELECT *, 1 as `group` FROM hol ORDER BY tks DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *, 2 as `group` FROM hol ORDER BY ths DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: It works. I think this is the best way for this case.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!